# How to get "Quantity Sold" from eBay website into excel using VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get item sold quantity (live) from eBay into excel using VBA?
This is what I found on stackoverflow so far.
But I don't get any results
I would appreciate any help
Thanks

```
Option Explicit
Sub readData()

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim profile As IHTMLElement6

XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.ebay.com/itm/VIRGINIA-CAVALIERS-FINAL-FOUR-National-FREAKIN-Champions-T-Shirt-Gildan/352639122861", False
XMLPage.send

If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then MsgBox XMLPage.statusText
html.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText


 For Each profile In html.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).Children
 Debug.Print profile.getElementsByClassName("vi-txt-underline")(0)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: can you tell us what of your code isn't working and what results you expect? ([mcve])

Comment: Sure, I am expecting to get "1" as the quantity of item sold.

Comment: I just need to pull the innertext (but just the numeric value) of the classname "vi-txt-underline" on that webpage and place it inside an excel sheet. Then I want to create the same code for 100 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the class is fine. There is only 1 match on the page so no need to grab multiple collections and loop. Simply use `querySelector` to return first match.

```
Public Sub GetNumberSold()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.ebay.com/itm/VIRGINIA-CAVALIERS-FINAL-FOUR-National-FREAKIN-Champions-T-Shirt-Gildan/352639122861", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    MsgBox html.querySelector(".vi-txt-underline").innerText
    Debug.Print Replace$(html.querySelector(".vi-txt-underline").innerText," sold",vbNullString)
    Debug.Print split(html.querySelector(".vi-txt-underline").innerText,chr$(32))(0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr, is there anyway It can read only the number part so I can create a graph in excel?

Comment: Use replace to replace the sold word or use split on the space and take the Lower bound of resultant array